# python 3.4.1 replacing part of a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I found out about the .replace(), but it works in 2.7.8, but I need it (or something similar), to work in 3.4.1. So I have...

```
message = ("hello")
message.replace("l", "t")
```

and I'm looking to get...

```
message = hetto
```

I know when it changes to hetto it makes no sense, but it is an example.

I tried:

```
 message = ("l")
 message.replace("l", "i")
```

and I still get:

```
message = l
```

Comment: Congrats. What is the question?

Comment: But the function work same in both versions ! so whats the problem ?

Comment: `message.replace("l", "i")` give `'i'` for me.

Comment: `.replace()` hasn't changed its behavior between Python 2 and 3 in this regard. You must be using it differently. Please also remove the unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 10):

You have to assign it back to itself to change the original string:

```
>>> message = message.replace("l", "t")
>>> message
'hetto'
```

Strings are immutable in Python. The only way to change a string is to create a new string.

Comment: I've added the explanation on why `.replace()` is not an inplace operation in Python. Feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` is a method of class `str`

```
>>> 'hello'.replace('l', 't')
'hetto'
```

**Post Edit**

The `replace` function is not *in-place* and returns the changed string. So you will have to reassign the value returned

```
message = "hello"
message = message.replace('l','t')
print(message)
```

will print

```
hetto
```

Also refer this [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

As [holdenweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564986/python-3-4-1-replacing-part-of-a-string/27565064?noredirect=1#comment43555676_27565064) mentioned in a comment, the `replace()` method works in the same way in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: There is no essential difference between Python 2 and Python 3's replace(). They are both methods of the string classes.

Comment: @holdenweb Yes, who told there is a difference?

Comment: Perhaps my comment would have been better attached to the question.

Comment: @holdenweb I didn't get you, Do kindly edit my answer if there is a major flaw in it.

Comment: No major flaw. I've edited the answer to give my very limited contribution less emphasis. It's simply that the questioner says "it works in 2.7.8, but I need it (or something similar), to work in 3.4.1," so I thought the information that 2 and 3 work the same way should be included with the answer.